# Induced metric on plane under a stereographic projection of a sphere

Tags: spherical-geometry

Let $S^2\subset\mathbb{E}^3$ be a sphere with radius 1 and center $(0,0,1)$ in cartesian coordinates. The northpole is point $(0,0,2)$ on the sphere and $Oxy$ is the xy-plane. Let $\pi:S^2\setminus N \to Oxy $ be a stereographic projection defined by $\pi(x,y,z)=(u,v)$ where $(u,v)$ is the intersection of the xy-plane and of a straight line through the the north pole and point $(x,y,z)$ on the sphere. I know $\pi$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\pi(x,y,z)=(u,v)=(\frac{2x}{2-z},\frac{2y}{2-z}),
\end{equation}
and its inverse $\pi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^2\to S^2\setminus N$ by
\begin{equation}
\pi^{-1}(u,v)=(\frac{4u}{u^2+v^2+4},\frac{4v}{u^2+v^2+4}, \frac{2(u^2+v^2)}{u^2+v^2+4})
\end{equation}
The sphere can be parametrized by
\begin{equation}
r(\theta,\phi)=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta).
\end{equation}
Now I am trying to understand what exactly the metric induced on the $Oxy$ plane under the stereographic projection means. Is it a way to measure distance from between points on the sphere through their projections on $\mathbb{R}^2$? How would you go about such a computation? Thank you.